# Inserting data in Json format into a database

Tags: json, database

I'm creating a new database, and all of the data I have are in Json format,is there a method i could use to easily insert all of the data into the db?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system). If you are using [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), and your version is recent enough, you can use the [`jsonb` data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) to do this:

```
create table my_json_data (
   my_id serial primary key,
   data jsonb not null
);
```

And then insert it with:

```
insert into my_json_data values (default, '{"hi": 10}');
```